# How can I export only selected row with hidden column in my datagridview into excel?

Tags: vb.net

I am a newbie then a self taught only,
I have a datagridview that will load the data from my database and it has a hidden column I want to export a selected row of data into excel but what I want to export is the only visible column in my datagridview to excel and the selected row only

I don't know how to do this right!

How can I combine this? the selected column and only visible column will be exported in my excel

```
 For i = 0 To SelectedRowCount - 1
            currentVisibleColumn = columnCollection.GetFirstColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)
            lastColumnExported = currentVisibleColumn
            For j = 1 To visibleColumnCount + 1
                Dim value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(currentVisibleColumn.Index).Value
                If value IsNot vbNullString Then
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j) = value.ToString()
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Index).Value.ToString()
                End If
                currentVisibleColumn = columnCollection.GetNextColumn(lastColumnExported, DataGridViewElementStates.Visible, DataGridViewElementStates.None)
                lastColumnExported = currentVisibleColumn
            Next
        Next
```

when I do this it gives me "'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: On what line does the exception occur?

Comment: on this line xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Index).Value.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be more like this:

```
Dim columns = (From column In DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)()
               Where column.Visible
               Order By column.DisplayIndex).ToArray()

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    For Each column In columns
        Dim value = row.Cells(column.Index)

        If value IsNot Nothing Then
            '...
        End If
    Next
Next
```

If you still get a `NullReferenceException`with that code then you'll need to be more specific about it to get more help but the solution to such issues is almost always the same.